# How can I set / change DNS using the command-prompt at windows 8

Tags: windows-8, dns, command-prompt

How can I set my DNS settings using the command-prompt or bat file at windows 8

I tried this:

```
netsh interface ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" source=static addr=none
```

but not worked.

Comment: First of all, run cmd as administrator.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

First, the network name is likely "Ethernet", not "Local Area Connection". To find out the name you can do this:

```
netsh interface show interface
```

Which will show the name under the "Interface Name" column (shown here in bold):

```
Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Ethernet
```

Now you can change the primary dns (index=1), assuming that your interface is static (not using dhcp):

```
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Ethernet" address=192.168.x.x index=1
```

---

**2018 Update -**  The command will work with either `dnsserver` (singular) or `dnsservers` (plural).  The following example uses the latter and is valid as well:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsservers "Ethernet" address=192.168.x.x index=1
```

Comment: It worked, thank you!  Do you know how to set the DNS to "automatic settings" ?

Comment: @Patrick: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29598445/3131693). Put `dhcp` in place of `static` in second command.

Comment: @chue-x Contrary to your statement about what's "likely", it is _extremely_ common for Windows to assign the name "Local Area Connection" to a network connection.

Comment: @RossPresser That was true for WinXP, Vista and 7 (not sure about earlier versions) but since Win8 that was changed to Ethernet.

Comment: From the built-in command help, the canonical name is "dnsservers". Though, you can input only "dns", "dnsse"... or even just "d". Similarly, "ip" is a shorthand for "ipv4".

Comment: These worked for me: `netsh interface ipv4 set dnsserver "Ethernet0" static address=208.67.222.222` and `netsh interface ipv4 set dnsserver "Ethernet0" address=208.67.222.222 index=1`

Answer (score 36):

To change DNS to automatic via command, you can run the following command:

```
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

Answer (score 27):

Here is another way to change DNS by using WMIC (Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line).

The commands must be run as administrator to apply.

Clear DNS servers:

```
wmic nicconfig where (IPEnabled=TRUE) call SetDNSServerSearchOrder ()
```

Set 1 DNS server:

```
wmic nicconfig where (IPEnabled=TRUE) call SetDNSServerSearchOrder ("8.8.8.8")
```

Set 2 DNS servers:

```
wmic nicconfig where (IPEnabled=TRUE) call SetDNSServerSearchOrder ("8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4")
```

Set 2 DNS servers on a particular network adapter:

```
wmic nicconfig where "(IPEnabled=TRUE) and (Description = 'Local Area Connection')" call SetDNSServerSearchOrder ("8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4")
```

Another example for setting the domain search list:

```
wmic nicconfig call SetDNSSuffixSearchOrder ("domain.tld")
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Everyone else proposes to **mess** with interface names like _"Local Area Connection"_ as if they are required.

Comment: I agree with @uvsmtid, this is the best answer. I started working on a much more complicated batch script and figured there had to be a better way. thanks!

Comment: For powershell replace `where (IPEnabled=TRUE)` with `where "IPEnabled=TRUE"`.

Comment: As in 2023, WMIC is deprecated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/deprecated-features

Answer (score 19):

There are little difference in command of *adding* AND *changing* DNS-IPs:

**To Add:**

```
Syntax:
   netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Network Interface Name" dns.server.ip index=1(for primary)2(for secondary)
Eg:
   netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Ethernet" 8.8.8.8 index=1
```

- Here, to know "Network Interface Name", type command ***`netsh interface show interface`***
- 8.8.8.8 is Google's recursive DNS server, use it, if your's not working

**To Set/Change:** (as OP asked this)

```
Syntax:
   netsh interface ipv4 set dnsservers "Network Interface Name" static dns.server.ip primary
Eg:
   netsh interface ipv4 set dnsservers "Wi-Fi" static 8.8.4.4 primary
   netsh interface ipv4 set dnsservers "Wi-Fi" dhcp
```

- Last parameter can be `none`:disable DNS, `both`:set for primary and secondary DNS both, primary: for primary DNS only. You can notice here we are not using index-parameter as we did in adding DNS.
- In the place of `static` you can type `dhcp` to make DNS setting automatic, but further parameter will not be required.

---

**Note:** Tested in windows 8,8.1 & 10.

Comment: The `primary` parameter at the end has nothing to do with primary/secondary DNS server. This parameter is used to control where the DNS client will try to dynamically register its name (`none`: do not register; `primary`: register at the primary DNS sufix; `both`: register at both, the primary DNS sufix and the connection-specific suffix). See `netsh interface ipv4 set dnsservers /?` for details.

Answer (score 18):

I wrote this script for switching DNS servers of all currently enabled interfaces to specific address:

```
@echo off

:: Google DNS
set DNS1=8.8.8.8
set DNS2=8.8.4.4

for /f "tokens=1,2,3*" %%i in ('netsh int show interface') do (
    if %%i equ Enabled (
        echo Changing "%%l" : %DNS1% + %DNS2%
        netsh int ipv4 set dns name="%%l" static %DNS1% primary validate=no
        netsh int ipv4 add dns name="%%l" %DNS2% index=2 validate=no
    )
)

ipconfig /flushdns

:EOF
```

Comment: Cool. I have improved on your answer by adding command param and filtering: https://gist.github.com/n074v41l4bl34u/e237c0f199b2bb68bf1c
 Any suggestions why my 'skip=2' option in FOR command is not working?

Answer (score 15):

None of the answers are working for me on Windows 10, so here's what I use:

```
@echo off

set DNS1=8.8.8.8
set DNS2=8.8.4.4
set INTERFACE=Ethernet

netsh int ipv4 set dns name="%INTERFACE%" static %DNS1% primary validate=no
netsh int ipv4 add dns name="%INTERFACE%" %DNS2% index=2

ipconfig /flushdns

pause
```

This uses Google DNS. You can get interface name with the command `netsh int show interface`

Answer (score 3):

Batch file for setting a new dns server

```
@echo off
rem usage: setdns <dnsserver> <interface>
rem default dsnserver is dhcp
rem default interface is Wi-Fi
set dnsserver="%1"
if %dnsserver%=="" set dnsserver="dhcp"
set interface="%2"
if %interface%=="" set interface="Wi-Fi"
echo Showing current DNS setting for interface a%interface%
netsh interface ipv4 show dnsserver %interface%
echo Changing dnsserver on interface %interface% to %dnsserver%
if %dnsserver% == "dhcp" netsh interface ipv4 set dnsserver %interface% %dnsserver%
if NOT %dnsserver% == "dhcp" netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver %interface% address=%dnsserver% index=1
echo Showing new DNS setting for interface %interface%
netsh interface ipv4 show dnsserver %interface%
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is your new friend: [QuickSetDNS](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/quick_set_dns.html), by NirSoft, amazing as usual.

[image: screenshot]

It also can be used in command line :) with these advantages over netsh:

- easier syntax, in particular for setting the alternate server
- automatically asks for privilege elevation

Just a few caveats:

- <del>supports only setting of IPv4, not of IPv6</del>

  - since QuickSetDNS 1.30, setting IPv6 DNS servers is also supported ;)
- <del>in command line, the adapter UUID should be used, not the friendly name (e.g. "Local Area Connection")</del>

  - since QuickSetDNS 1.21, connection names are also supported ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Now you can change the primary dns (index=1), assuming that your interface is static (not using dhcp)

You can set your DNS servers statically even if you use DHCP to obtain your IP address.

Example under Windows 7 to add two DN servers, the command is as follows:

`netsh interface ipv4 add dns "Local Area Connection" address=192.168.x.x index=1
netsh interface ipv4 add dns "Local Area Connection" address=192.168.x.x index=2`